# How can I write output of MATLAB to MS Word?

Tags: matlab

I am reading the input of the MATLAB code from an Excel file using `xlsread`, after the calculation I am exporting to Word for writing out the report(writetoword.m). In Excel, there is a string which I should read in MATLAB and output in Word.

In Excel file(input.xlsx) it is written 'shoe'.

I read using

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('input.xlsx');
eng = txt(14,19); % the word 'shoe' in that excel cell
```

In `writetoword.m`, I wrote,

```
test = eng;
WordText(ActXWord,test,Style,[0,1]);

function WordText(actx_word_p,text_p,style_p,enters_p,color_p)
    if(enters_p(1))
        actx_word_p.Selection.TypeParagraph;
    end
    actx_word_p.Selection.Style = style_p;
    if(nargin == 5)
        actx_word_p.Selection.Font.Color=color_p;     
    end

    actx_word_p.Selection.TypeText(text_p);
    actx_word_p.Selection.Font.Color='wdColorAutomatic';
    for k=1:enters_p(2)    
        actx_word_p.Selection.TypeParagraph;
    end
return
```

It is not printing anything. The error is in the line

```
actx_word_p.Selection.TypeText(text_p);
```

now if I write

```
test = 'eng';
WordText(ActXWord,test,Style,[0,1]);
```

It will come as eng and not shoe.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning `txt` as a [cell](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) instead of a string. Use `eng = txt{14,19};` instead.